# DLNA app that supports output orientation?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, video, images, dlna, orientation

On the Samsung Galaxy S2 is a DLNA client / server application called AllShare.

This can direct audio, video and images to a DLNA consumer on the network the phone is on.

In my case, this happens to be a Samsung TV.  This works automatically, I push out a video or image to the TV, and it appears (without doing anything to the TV, very cool).

The only hitch is the video and image orientation isn't taken into consideration, so all images and video appear in a single orientation (landscape), regardless of the orientation they were captured in.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the TV to recognise the orientation, or get the S2 to orient what it sends to the TV?

Perhaps there is a DLNA app that can support on the fly rotation?